# The type or namespace name 'MySqlBulkLoader' could not be found

Tags: mysql, bulkloader

I'm trying to use the MySQL .Net connector to upload csv to MySQL but there's no  'MySqlBulkLoader' object in the dll. I downloaded the binary from the MySQL site.

> using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
>   ...
>
> MySqlBulkLoader bl = new MySqlBulkLoader(conn);

Has Error: The type or namespace name 'MySqlBulkLoader' could not be found

There's sample code all over the place using this.

Anyone see this before, what could be happening here?

Comment: Have you referenced the binary from your project? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Have you tried another framework version? Don't use the client profile.

Comment: Yes tried that too, changed to .net 2.